# Convert EC Public Key from SubjectPublicKeyInfo form into "traditional" form

Tags: openssl

Hope I got the terms correct.

I currently have an EC public key in the form

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxxx
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

which I understand is the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` form. I would like to convert this into the form

```
-----BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY-----
xxxxx
-----END EC PUBLIC KEY-----
```

using commands like `openssl` or similar. I can't seem to find a `RSAPublicKey_{in|out}` for the `openssl ec` command. I would like to be able to convert the public key in both `DER` and `PEM` forms.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27930720 "How can I transform between the two styles of public key format, one “BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY”, the other is “BEGIN PUBLIC KEY”") your answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's for RSA Keys only. I cannot find the analogue for EC keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenSSL does not support any "BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY" format and (AFAIK) no such format exists. There is a "traditional" public key format for RSA ("BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY"), which is essentially a PEM encoded PKCS#1 structure. Later standards defined how to encode public keys in an algorithm agnostic way (SubjectPublicKeyInfo) and so there isn't always a "traditional" format version.

You can check the known OpenSSL PEM types by looking in the openssl pem header file (include/openssl/pem.h). You will notice that there is no "EC PUBLIC KEY" entry. There is an "RSA PUBLIC KEY", "DSA PUBLIC KEY" and "ECDSA PUBLIC KEY", but the latter two are not used anywhere in the OpenSSL codebase (i.e. they only exist in the header file).

There are "traditional" formats for private keys. To convert a PKCS8 private key to traditional form use:

```
openssl ec -in p8file.pem -out tradfile.pem
```

The ec command also recognises the "-inform DER" and "-outform DER" options. So, for example, to convert a DER PKCS8 private key file into PEM traditional you could use:

```
openssl ec -inform DER -in p8file.der -out tradfile.pem
```

Or to convert a PEM PKCS8 private key file into DER traditional use:

```
openssl ec -in p8file.pem -outform DER -out tradfile.der
```

You can also go the other way, i.e. traditional form private key to PKCS8:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in tradfile.pem -out p8file.pem
```

The pkcs8 command above also recognises the -inform and -outform options.

Comment: This does not work:


$ openssl ec -in ecdsa_public_key.pem -out test.pem
read EC key
unable to load Key
140111551870616:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY PRIVATE KEY

Even if you add `-pubin` and `pubout`, it doesn't change the key format. I've tried this before.

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Misread the original question. My answer was for private keys. I have edited the answer to provide additional info about public keys too.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I must have been mistaken when I saw `BEGIN EC PUBLIC KEY` somewhere. Do you know how I could get `ECDSA PUBLIC KEY` instead? 

EDIT: Oops. I just saw they're not used. Thanks